# How to avoid mysqldump warning "Skipping the data of table mysql.event"

Tags: debian, mysql

After a recent Debian upgrade on my LAMP webserver to *Wheezy*, mysqldump is throwing a warning:

```
-- Warning: Skipping the data of table mysql.event. Specify the --events option explicitly.
```

Events seems to be something special. Man page for mysqldump:

```
   *   --events, -E

       Include Event Scheduler events for the dumped databases in the output.
```

I have tried adding `--skip-events` to tell mysqldump that this is explicitly the behaviour I wanted (although I don't know why...) but it still generates the warning.

How can I (a) stop it emitting this warning, *or* (b) otherwise include this awkward table, if its something I should be keeping.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This appears to be a [feature](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68376) for which there is a workaround

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --events --ignore-table=mysql.event mysql > /tmp/mysql.sql"
```

This says dump the event (--events) table and then ignore it.

Answer (score 9):

For folks that are using [automysqlbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) you will need to do the following:

1. Modify or Create your ~/.my.cnf and create a mysqldump section by adding the following

   ```
   [mysqldump]
   events
   ignore-table = mysql.events
   ```

Using this solution guarantees that if you upgrade [automysqlbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) that your changes won't be erased. Happy backing up!